# Codeigniter MVC. Going from summary information on one View to detailed Information in another View

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok, so I have views that provide summary information regarding user entries. Users can create entries for different "programs" (categories more or less) and different "vendors" etc. So the Program View will show some summary information for each program as well as how many entries each program has. The Vendor View will show summary information about each vendor as well as how many entries exist for each vendor.

How do I code a button that users can click to take them to a view of entries for that program or vendor. I'm getting confused because I don't think you are supposed to access a controller from a view but I want the user to be able to see summary information in different ways and then click to get to the detailed data.

So the Program View might look like: 
Page Title: All Programs

Program: Program 1
Start Date: 5/5/13
End Date: 5/5/14
Button: |Click to view entries|

Program: Program 2
Start Date: 6/1/13
End Date: 2/15/14
Button: |Click to view entries|

What I would really like to do is call a model I created that accepts an array which acts as a filter. It works nicely when called from a controller but I don't think I can do that looks like this:

```
public function get_entries($filter, $option = false)
{
$this->db->where($filter);
$this->db->from('item i');
$this->db->join('program p', 'p.Id=i.program_Id');
$this->db->join('vendor v', 'v.Id=i.vendor_Id');
$this->db->join('item_type it', 'it.Id=i.item_type_Id');
$this->db->join('item_type_category itc', 'itc.item_type_Id=it.Id');
$this->db->join('category c', 'c.Id=itc.category_Id');
$this->db->select('i.*, p.programName, v.VENDNM, it.name, c.catName');
$this->db->select('(SELECT FORMAT(i.cost, "c")) AS cost', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
if ($option === false){
return $result;
}
elseif ($option === "count"){
return count($result);
}
}
```

Comment: if you want to view all entries of program 1, the you can go with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy -- just use a form that has fields that determine the ranges you want to search on. The address that you use on the form will first go to your controller -- then the method. Using Codeigniters form helper if your controller is 'reports' and a method 'search':

```
 echo form_open('reports/search');
```

then in your 'reports' controller in a method called 'search'

```
Verify the Form Using the Form Validation class.
ALWAYS verify user input even if you are just using drop down menus. 

If the form does not verify 
  show the form view again with an error message

Else
  do the search with the values provided by the form. 
  Typically doing this search and passing back the results 
  (or False for no results) will happen in the Model

If there are no database results 
   show the form view again with a no results message

Else if there are results
   pass results to a view page which will display them.
```

Form Helper
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Form Validation 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

and take a look at this tutorial -- will show you many of the basic code patterns you need - 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html